# running an image created through Docker in lxc

Tags: docker, lxc, lxd

I want to run an image which I have already created and uploaded on the docker hub. Is it possible to run that image on lxc/lxd? Basically I want to do performance comparison between docker and lxc.

I have installed skopeo, umoci, go-md2man and jq.

Now, when I try to run the command lxc-create c1 -t oci – --url docker://awaisaz/test:part2
it gives trust policy error. /etc/containers/policy.json not such file or directory

Can anyone suggest me a solution or alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to run a docker container inside an LXC Container.

firstly, you need to make docker process up and running inside an lxc container.

```
   sudo lxc config edit <lxc-container-name>
```

In Config Object, Add

```
   linux.kernel_modules: overlay,ip_tables
   security.nesting: true
   security.privileged: true
```

Then Exit from that YAML File, And Restart the LXC Container

```
   sudo lxc restart <container_name>
```

After Successfull restart of LXC Container.

exec into that container by

```
   sudo lxc exec <container_name> /bin/bash
```

Then,

```
   sudo rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db
```

Restart Docker Service,

```
   service docker restart (In LXC Container)
```

Then you can use docker process in LXC Container as if you are in a VM.

Comment: This answers a different question. @Awais wants to run a docker IMAGE in lxc, not a docker INSTANCE in lxc. That means lxc pulling the image and using it as rootfs for a new lxc container.